# Функция не видит переменную-список?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, атрибуты

В результате выполнения кода возникает ошибка `NameError`

не видит массив `numbers`.

Пробовала через `global` (как в коде), но не помогает.

Если прописать просто методы без класса - работает, но в этом случае нужен класс.

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    ...
        
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']        
    def checking(self):
        
        def changeEnable(firstIndex = 0, param = False):
            global numbers
            for i in range(firstIndex, len(numbers)):
                getattr(self.ui, "pb_%s" %(numbers[i])).setEnabled(param)
                
        changeEnable(0, True)
        ...
```

Comment: `MyWin.numbers`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()    
        ...

# ----> vvvv <---------------------------------------------------    
        self.numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']  

    ...
      
    def checking(self):

        def changeEnable(firstIndex = 0, param = False):
            # global numbers

# ---------------------------------------> vvvv <---------------- 
            for i in range(firstIndex, len(self.numbers)):
                getattr(self.ui, "pb_%s" %(self.numbers[i])).setEnabled(param)

        changeEnable(0, True)
        ...
```

Comment: спасибо, работает теперь. только не нужно было при инициализации self писать